# Informatica Power Exchange

Tags: informatica, informatica-powerexchange

Can any one suggest where can I download informatica power exchange setup.
Need to work on social media data, required pwx setup.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't... The only place I know of where some Informatica tools are available is edelivery.oracle.com. It would be great is someone could prove me wrong :)

Comment: No Maciejg, you are right. Oracle version doesnt have PWX for social media. Another way is to talk to their sales team, if you already have a relationship, you can ask them a free certificate and the tool. You can use powervernter for cloud for free - I think it has social media extractor.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations, libraries, downloads, tutorials, and other off-site resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow.